# Make GitLab pipeline failed using Jelastic API

Tags: gitlab, continuous-deployment, jelastic

I'm using the Jelastic API with Gitlab CI in order to deploy an application.
With the [cli tool](https://docs.jelastic.com/api/), I use the `ExecCmdById` method to execute a script on a remote server.

The problem is that my pipeline always succeed, even if the API returns an error of execution. The remote command fails but the local command succeed because it doesn't read the json response.

I've tried something but it's an ugly fix:
See my pipeline here => https://pastebin.com/FSrUtNne

Is there a real solution to make the Gitlab pipeline fail ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current version of Jelastic CLI cannot exit with non-zero code after the command execution in case if API response has non-zero code in result object, but the use case use described in your question sounds very reasonable that is why in next version of Jelastic CLI client this behavior will be changed to the one you stated. Thank you for your feedback. Jelastic team appreciate your help!

Comment: Thanks ! I really appreciate this